# How to make an Invoice as paid using PHP code at quickbooks online sdk

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have created Invoice using this code : https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/blob/master/src/_Samples/InvoiceCreate.php

But how can make this invoice as paid using PHP sdk?

Here I am getting payment using paper check ... so I am creating Invoice just for bookkeeping and not sending to client. ( not using QBO Payment )
so when I rec payment how to mark invoice as paid using php sdk ?

I try to update "Balance" as 0 but its not marking as paid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd really recommend you use The library written by Keith Palmer for this as the QBO documentation is garbage that's all over the place.

With that being said:

You need to return the transaction Id from the invoice:

```
return $resultingObj->TxnId;
```

And then create a payment using supplying that transaction id:

```
$invoiceId = CreateInvoice(); //returns txnId above

$qbLinkedInvoice = new IPPLinkedTxn();
$qbLinkedInvoice->TxnId = $invoiceId;
$qbLinkedInvoice->TxnType = 'Invoice';

$qbLine = new IPPLine();
$qbLine->Amount = "";//set amount;
$qbLine->LinkedTxn = $qbLinkedInvoice;

$qbPayment = new IPPPayment();
$qbPayment->CustomerRef = "";//customer id
$qbPayment->TotalAmt = "";//I think this must match amount above;
$qbPayment->Line = array($qbLine);

$createdQbPayment = $this->dataService->Add($qbPayment);
```

Comment: Got it. I have to create "Payment" against "Invoice".

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reference to go to for these Objects? QB Documentation doesn't even mention these objects. I kind of have the QB PHP SDK working but this seems so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a 100% sure about this, but I think you have to create payments for that invoice amounting to the full sum of the invoice. To see the required contents of the payload, see https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/payment.

Comment: Got it. I have to create "Payment" against "Invoice".

Thanks